# Android Studio gradle Sync Error Failed to resolve

Tags: android, gradle

Whenever I try to start Android Studio, I am getting the error

> Failed to resolve:junit:junit:4.12

I already added the code line -

```
repositories {maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' } }
```

Still I am getting the error of gradle sync. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which repositories section did you add it to? Can you show more of your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked, the [maven url](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) your are using is valid.

And you can actually drill down to find JUnit 4.12 there:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/

I tried the same gradle script setup as you mentioned, it worked.

Maybe you could try:

- **clean** your build
- check if your **build variant** is correct
- maybe there is some **boolean flag** in your gradle script

But the latter two usually cause issues like "`Could not find class org.junit.xxx`", not like the "`failed to resolve`" issue you have.  Still, give a check and try please.